# How to implement 'Not In' Filter in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a field in SSRS that i need to filter on.
For 3 table I can use a IN filter.
But I am in need to use a NOT IN operator. The field contains numeric values.

I need to be able to say not in `(30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39)`

I can't do it within the dataset either, it needs to be a filter.

How should I achieve it ?

Comment: please provide an example of the code you have tried and the community can help show you what might need changing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an expression to determine which values are going to be filtered.

Go to `Tablix properties`/ `Filters`

In `expression` use:

```
=IIF(Array.IndexOf(split("30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39",","),
CStr(Fields!YourField.Value))>-1,"Exclude","Include")
```

For Operator use:

```
=
```

For `Value` use:

```
="Include"
```

Let me know if this can help you

Comment: For anyone who wants to use this with a parameter, just replace the string array ("30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39") with the following code: (Join(Parameters!YourParameter.Value, ",")). This can filter the table with values that are NOT IN values from a parameter, which is what I needed the NOT IN filter for. The final modified expression will look something like this: =IIf(Array.IndexOf(Split((Join(Parameters!YourParameter.Value, ",")), ","), CStr(Fields!YourField.Value)) > -1, "Exclude", "Include")

Answer (score 1):

For a variation of the selected answer that I find easier to use, please see below. This is in a Visibility expression, but should be easily ported to a Filter expression by setting Expression type to Boolean and comparing if `Expression = False`:

`=IIf(InStr("unwanted values here", Fields!fieldToCheck.Value), True, False)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would like to say that, to my knowledge, `NOT IN` is not available in list of operators for filters.

To Achieve the same thing in other way, please refer the following link..it might help you...

http://blog.datainspirations.com/2011/01/20/working-with-reporting-services-filters-part-4-creating-a-not-in-filter/